# «Парокиальный» или «парохиальный»?

Tags: орфография, значение-слов, выбор-слов

Пожалуйста, подскажите, есть ли различия между словами «парокиальный» и «парохиальный». Если есть, то в чем они заключаются? В каких случаях уместен каждый из вариантов? Оба ли допустимы в книжной речи?

Встречал слово в терминах «парокиальное политическое участие», «парокиальная политическая культура», «парокиальный альтруизм».

*Не нашел слова в словарях, не получил ответа от Грамоты.ру. Поэтому буду особо благодарен ответившему.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово одно, но пишется и произносится по-разному в зависимости от этимологических предпочтений.Искать его следует в справочниках по политологии и словарях иностранных слов.

Сидней Верба и Габриэль Алмонд создали свою теоретическую модель политической культуры. Политическое участие первого типа они называют парокиальным, то есть таким, которое ограничено элементарными интересами; второго типа – подданническим, а третьего – партиципаторным. Также эти ученые выделили переходные формы активности, в которых сочетаются черты двух граничащих типов. - Читайте подробнее на FB.ru: http://fb.ru/article/43946/politicheskoe-uchastie-grajdan

http://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-foreign2-term-27477.htm

В словаре иностранных слов Чудинова 1910г.: ПАРОХИАЛЬНЫЙ(греч.). К приходу, к пастве принадлежащий или к ним относящийся.

Парокиальная (приходская) политическая культура(англ. parochial) , от гр. para —около, возле, oikos — место обитания, домохозяйство;

иначе — местечковая, патриархальная, для которой характерно отсутствие интереса людей к политике, знаний о политической системе и существенных ожиданий от ее функционирования;

http://texts.news/nauka-politika/struktura-funktsii-politicheskoy.html

Так что если хочется произнести близко к этимологическому источнику - греч., то пишем К-oikos,ближе к англ. - Х -parochial

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Именно в описанном Вами контексте (теория Алмонда и Вербы) меня в первую очередь интересует употребление. В 1910 году, насколько я понял, нормой было написание через «х» — но тогда слово употреблялось в совсем ином значении. Англичане произносят в слове «parochial» звук [k], как и в других греческих словах с сочетанием ch. Можно ли сделать вывод, что писать «парокиальный» предпочтительнее сегодня?

Comment: Я тоже так думаю. Парохиальный - транслитерация (а не произношение, как я сначала написала). Просто перенесли ch = х, когда слово пришло в русский язык.

Answer (score 4):

Интересный вопрос. До сих пор встречал только написание «парохиальный». А основные два контекста — это эволюционная теория возникновения альтруизма (парохиальный альтруизм) и обсуждение принципа Коперника (парохиальность как его отрицание, то есть убеждение в исключительности нашего места и роли во Вселенной).
Сделал поиск в Гугле. Написание «парохиальный» встречается 3 тыс. раз, а написание «парокиальный» — 83 раза. Разница в 36 раз в пользу «парохиального». Видимо, это приговор :)